# CSS - stretching side imgs

Tags: html, css

I want to archive this img layout with CSS:
http://666kb.com/i/czotlngmz2miu66q1.gif

- 1 & 2 & 3 have the same height of 911px
- 2 must be centered and has a fixed width of 800px
- img 1 & 3 should be stretched to fill the remaining space on left and right side
- the imgs should not overlay each other

My HTML Code is a bunch of div tags, nothing special, so I don't think there's need to post it.

For me this sounded like a simple task at first time, but ended up wasting 20h and archived nothing.

has anyone a idea to make this?

Edit1:
All asked for code so I’ll show u what i just came up with:

```css
#page {
    display:table-row;
    height:911px
}

#logo {
    background:url(../images/logo.png) top center no-repeat;
    width:800px;
    height:293px;
    position:absolute
}

#side_L {
    display:table-cell;
    background:url(../images/bg_L.png) no-repeat right top / 100% 911px;
    min-width:50%;
    height:911px
}

#mid {
    display:table-cell;
    background:url(../images/main_bg.png) top center no-repeat;
    width:800px;
    height:911px;
    max-width:800px
}

#side_R {
    display:table-cell;
    background:url(../images/bg_R.png) no-repeat left top / 100% 911px;
    min-width:50%;
    height:911px
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
        <div id="side_L"></div>

        <div id="mid">
            <div id="logo"></div>

            <div id="content"></div>

            <div id="foot"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="side_R"></div>
    </div>
```

problem here --> it somehow works but I looks dirty anyway.
Is there a better solution?
All stuff from now on like logo, content & foot and such need a ->margin-top: -911px...
that can't be the best way.

Comment: Can you provide sample codes?

Comment: That's the easy part. The hard part is deciding what to do in browser windows narrower than 800px. Anyway, Alberto is right: you should show some effort at solving it yourself, e.g. something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boafz90s/).

Comment: @erinas, when you post your code here you can use the button in the editor and put the code in the right places. I have just edited your post again, please try and maintain this formatting.

Comment: @odedta Turning the code into a snippet won't help a bit, because there wouldn't be any output.

Comment: Ever heard of good practice? :)

Comment: @odedta thank you odedta, i am more or less new here so i didn't know that :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulating a table is one way, but in this case, you can simply float the first two divs to the left, leaving the last div to take up the remaining space. The trick is the `calc` function that is used to give the left div half the width of what is left over when you put an 800px div in the window, so that the right div will have the same width.

Note that the sizes of the divs are too large to show in the snippet window correctly, so you'll have to go full screen to see it in all its glory.
Also note that I replaced the background pictures (which wouldn't show) with background colors.

```css
#side_L {
  float: left;
  background: #DFD;
  width: calc(50% - 400px);
  height: 911px;
}
#mid {
  background: #DFF;
  float: left;
  width: 800px;
  height: 911px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
#side_R {
  background: #DDF;
  height: 911px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="side_L"></div>
    <div id="mid">
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <div id="foot"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="side_R"></div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Best answer so far: Mr Lister!

Comment: That really helped me thanks dude didn't know about calc function in css and also thanks @odedta for his fast answering this morning =p

Answer (score 0):

How about this template?

```css
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav_left {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;       
}
#nav_right {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float: right;
    padding:5px;       
}
#section {
    width:800px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;    
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;    
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav_left">
London<br>
Paris<br>
Tokyo<br>
</div>

<div id="section">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
    </p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="nav_right">
    London<br>
    Paris<br>
    Tokyo<br>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Copyright © W3Schools.com
</div>
```

Comment: I took a template from w3schools and just added a right nav, something wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe you could have trimmed it down a bit; it looks a bit fluffy now compared to the OP's question.

Comment: Well, he/she didn't make our life easier either :P

Comment: well it was actually a nice idea but the sample code works with navis and they are mostly fixed sized but i use img 1 & 3 for bg imgs 200px but thats why i ask here. They must be -> streched <- depending on browser width. @odedta i'll post a bit code i a few min ;)